# WDK : get processId by name.exe

Tags: process, kernel, wdk

I'm developing a driver in Windows Filtering Platform and I need the process ID of another process to do what I need to do.
I know only the file name of that process (name.exe).

In win32 I could use the function *CreateToolhelp32Snapshot* to get the list of all processes and I could search the PID there.
( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834(VS.85).aspx )

Unfortunately in kernel mode this stuff is not available.
Anyone know how can I obtain the processID knowing only the binary name, by kernel space?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

You can use ZwQuerySystemInformation with SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation information class. This is analogous to CreateToolhelp32Snapshot. However, some of the structs are undocumented. Here's an example:
http://www.volynkin.com/procenum.htm 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725506.aspx